# How to cause deadlock on MySQL

Tags: mysql, deadlock

For test purposes, I need to generate a **"1213: Deadlock"** on **MySQL** so that UPDATE query can't update a table.

I am not not quite sure how to cause deadlock?

Comment: Take some time reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I Cause a Deadlock in MySQL for Testing Purposes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269676/how-can-i-cause-a-deadlock-in-mysql-for-testing-purposes)

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer. From my experience, 1213 is the deadlock caused by optimistic locking used by Galera. It may be caused by other conditions as well. This is different than the deadlocks I have seen in the answers so far, which I believe would be 1205 errors.

Answer (score 9):

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `marks` INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO table1 (id, name, marks) VALUES (1, "abc", 5);

INSERT INTO table1 (id, name, marks) VALUES (2, "xyz", 1);
```

### First Window

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE table1 SET marks=marks-1 WHERE id=1; -- X lock acquired on 1
```

## Second Window

### Update Again

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE table1 SET marks=marks+1 WHERE id=2; -- X lock acquired on 2
UPDATE table1 SET marks=marks-1 WHERE id=1; -- LOCK WAIT!
```

## First Window (continued)

```
UPDATE table1 SET marks=marks+1 WHERE id=2; -- DEADLOCK!
COMMIT;
```

Comment: After executing query in first window `update table1 set marks = marks + 1 where id = 2;` we got error in terminal: `ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`. We use Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.33-MariaDB

Answer (score 7):

There are numerous posts for this by using two sessions.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/309/code-to-simulate-deadlock

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/08/how-to-deliberately-cause-a-deadlock-in-mysql/

**Method copied from the second article above**

First, choose an unused table name. I’ll use test.innodb_deadlock_maker. Here are the statements you need to execute:

```
create table test.innodb_deadlock_maker(a int primary key) engine=innodb;
insert into test.innodb_deadlock_maker(a) values(0), (1);
```

Now the table and its data are set up. Next, execute the following on two different connections:

-- connection 0

```
set transaction isolation level serializable;
start transaction;
select * from test.innodb_deadlock_maker where a = 0;
update test.innodb_deadlock_maker set a = 0 where a <> 0;
```

-- connection 1

```
set transaction isolation level serializable;
start transaction;
select * from test.innodb_deadlock_maker where a = 1;
update test.innodb_deadlock_maker set a = 1 where a <> 1;
```

Comment: I couldn't get the method described above to cause a deadlock in MySQL 5.6.40.  The method described at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/309/code-to-simulate-deadlock worked for me.