# Forcing a deadlock with MySQL transactions

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, deadlock

I'm trying to force a deadlock for a demonstration and with Oracle, it seems to be working, but in MySQL, for some reason, the query goes through...

Why is my example not causing a deadlock??

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void executeStartupTask() throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Connecting to MySQL via: " + databaseUrl);
    LOGGER.info("Seeding database...");
    seedDatabase();

    Thread providerResetThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Connection connection = getMySQLDataSource().getConnection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            // 1st device model always GMETER
            updateDeviceModel("E000000001", "GMETER", connection);

            LOGGER.info("Sleep for " + genericTimeoutLength + "  milliseconds");
            Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(genericTimeoutLength));

            // 2st device model always EMETER
            updateDeviceModel("E000000002", "EMETER",  connection);

            connection.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    providerResetThread.start();

    // Resetting the model type
    try {
        Connection connection = getMySQLDataSource().getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        updateDeviceModel("E000000002", "NONE", connection);
        updateDeviceModel("E000000001", "NONE", connection);

        connection.commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    providerResetThread.join();
    LOGGER.info("EXECUTION SUCCESSFUL!");
}


public void updateDeviceModel(String deviceId, String model, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    LOGGER.info("Updating model for device " + deviceId);
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE device_entity SET model = '" + model + "' WHERE deviceId = '" + deviceId + "'");
    statement.execute();
}
```

The log goes as following:

```
2022-02-08 09:59:32,950 INFO  method: [Thread-2] interview.InterviewApplication (InterviewApplication.java:126) - Updating model for device E000000001
2022-02-08 09:59:32,950 INFO  method: [main] interview.InterviewApplication (InterviewApplication.java:126) - Updating model for device E000000002
2022-02-08 09:59:32,955 INFO  method: [Thread-2] interview.InterviewApplication (InterviewApplication.java:56) - Sleep for 5000  milliseconds
2022-02-08 09:59:37,965 INFO  method: [Thread-2] interview.InterviewApplication (InterviewApplication.java:126) - Updating model for device E000000002
2022-02-08 09:59:37,975 INFO  method: [main] interview.InterviewApplication (InterviewApplication.java:126) - Updating model for device E000000001
2022-02-08 09:59:43,046 INFO  method: [main] interview.InterviewApplication (InterviewApplication.java:92) - EXECUTION SUCCESSFUL!
```

Comment: Why should this give deadlock?

Comment: This is just a comment not related to your deadlock task, but your UPDATE statement is vulnerable to SQL injection. It's ironic that you're using `prepareStatement()` but still relying on string-concatenation instead of using query parameters.

Comment: There are a few pieces of information missing that might affect the deadlock test. What is the table definition for your `device_entity` table? What is the duration of `genericTimeoutLength`? Do any of the updates succeed in your test? If so, which ones, the first thread or the second thread?

Comment: @BillKarwin genericTimeoutLength is 5000ms, and here's the code repository, just run deploy-database.bat, and yeah this code is garbage, I'm more looking for a deadlock exemple
https://gitlab.com/MathieuAuclair/trilliant-interview

Comment: @pringi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552766/how-to-cause-deadlock-on-mysql/31552794

Comment: I've tested directly in MySQL and a deadlock occurs. Are you sure that you are obtaining a different connection in the thread-2 and in main thread?

Comment: Good point, I'll log onto my computer later and try that!

Comment: @pringi This Doesn't seem to be the issue, I tried instantiating the connection from the same data source, tried to implement a connection pool, did not seem to change the behaviour... ?? Have you tried to clone the repository see if you get the same behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code in the repository that you indicted, I have the expected behaviour as you can see in the following image:

[image]

I've used MySQL 5.6 (also in the latest version the same occurs).

Also the code in the repository is not the same you posted here. When using the code you posted here the behaviour does not occur.

If you observe closely:

```
updateDeviceModel("E000000001", "GMETER", connection);

updateDeviceModel("E000000001", "NONE", connection);
```

Is using Ids that do not exist in database.

Your seed database uses IDs "E1" and "E2".
In practice you are updating nothing.

Changing your execute statement to

```
final int update = statement.executeUpdate();
```

You can see how many records were affected (zero).

So no deadlock occurs.

In your repository code, if you do the same, you will see that one record was updated in each call.